# how to do a count query when using rust diesel

Tags: rust, rust-diesel

I am doing a count query using rust `1.59.0` diesel `diesel = { version = "1.4.8", features = ["postgres","64-column-tables","chrono"] }` following this [document](https://docs.diesel.rs/diesel/dsl/fn.count.html), this is my code looks like right now:

```
use diesel::{ExpressionMethods, QueryDsl, QueryResult, RunQueryDsl};
use diesel::dsl::count;
use rocket::serde::json::Json;
use rust_wheel::config::db::config;

pub fn channel_fav_count(req_channel_id: &i64) -> i32 {
    use crate::model::diesel::dolphin::dolphin_schema::article_favorites::dsl::*;
    let connection = config::establish_connection();
    let query = article_favorites
        .filter(channel_id.eq(req_channel_id));
    let query_result = query.select(count(id)).first(&connection);
    return query_result.unwrap_or(0);
}
```

when I compile the code, shows error like this:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `i32: FromSql<BigInt, Pg>` is not satisfied
    --> src/service/app/cruise/article/article_fav_service.rs:11:48
     |
11   |     let query_result = query.select(count(id)).first(&connection);
     |                                                ^^^^^ the trait `FromSql<BigInt, Pg>` is not implemented for `i32`
```

why did this happen? what should I do to fix this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first thing you must know it's query count return i64 not i32, so you must convert i64 to i32 by your self

maybe like this

```
let query_result = query.select(count(id)).first(&connection).map(|x| x as i32);
```

also you can get count by filter query like below

```rust
users
    .filter(user_id.eq(_user_id))
    .count()
    .get_result(conn) // Result<i64, Error>
```

for your code it's like this

```rust
article_favorites
    .filter(channel_id.eq(req_channel_id))
    .count()
    .get_result(&connection)
```